# Angular 2 - RouteChange is not working when tried to access the link/component for second time

Tags: angular

My html for homepage component

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li [class.active]="makeActive('home')"><a routerLink="home">Users</a></li>
        <li [class.active]="makeActive('posts')"><a routerLink="posts">Posts</a></li>
      </ul>

</nav>

<div class="container">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

My homecomponent.ts

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {UsersService} from './users.service';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from '@angular/http';
import {OnInit, OnDestroy} from '@angular/core'



@Component({
    selector : 'home',
    template : `<h1>Home</h1>
            <p><a class="btn btn-primary" routerLink="Newuser">Add User</a></p>
    `,
    providers : [UsersService, HTTP_PROVIDERS]
})

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit{

    usersList: any[];
    constructor(private _usersService: UsersService){}
    ngOnInit(){
        this._usersService.getUsers()
            .subscribe(users => this.usersList = users);
    }
}
```

When I click on the AddUser button for the first time, the page url becomes localhost:3000/Newuser and the page renders properly, then after clicking on home will render the home view.
Then if i click the adduser again the url becomes localhost:3000/home/Newuser and the newuser view is not loaded.

Here is my router file

```
import {Router, RouterModule} from '@angular/router';

import {HomeComponent} from './home.component';
import {PostsComponent} from './posts.component';
import {UserAdditionComponent} from './user-addition.component'



export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot([
{path: '', component: HomeComponent},
{path: 'posts', component: PostsComponent},
{path: 'Newuser', component: UserAdditionComponent},
{path: '**', component: HomeComponent}
    ])
```

Comment: any errors in the browser console?

Comment: I don't see any errors... when i click on the adduser, it just appends newuser to the url

Comment: Can you post your routing module ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because `routerLink` takes the *relative path*.

If you go to `/home` it'll append `Newuser` to `/home/...`

To solve this, you have to add an `'/'` before the `Newuser`:

```
<p><a class="btn btn-primary" routerLink="/Newuser">Add User</a></p>
```